# find /data/oozie-admi/ -type d -ctime +1 | xargs rm -rf [0] command deleted /data/oozie-admi/ folder

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

`/data/oozie-admi/` folder contains multiple directories.

This command

```
find /data/oozie-admi/ -type d -ctime +1 | xargs rm -rf [0]
```

deleted `/data/oozie-admi/` folder . Need to find out scenarios in which the folder will get deleted.

Comment: What did you expect would happen? And do you know the difference between `ctime` and `mtime`, and between `ctime 1` and `ctime +1`?

Answer (score 1):

[This page on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21579/difference-between-ctime-1-and-ctime-1-in-find-command) gives a good description of what `ctime` does in the `find` command:

> According to the `find` man page,
>
> ```
> -ctime n
>     File's status was last changed n*24 hours ago.
>
> +n for greater than n
> ```
>
> Therefore `-ctime +1` means the file status must have changed at least 48 hours ago.

The `-type d` would specify to only return directories.

So `find /data/oozie-admi/ -type d -ctime +1` will match any and all directories that have *not* been changed in the last 48 hours.

As an example if you have a folder `/data/oozie-admi/fish` that was created more than 48 hours ago and that is where a bunch of updates happen within 48 hours in that folder then that folder will be excluded from your match, but `/data/oozie-admi/` will not be excluded unless files have been changed there.

`xargs rm -rf` would delete any and all directories that get passed to it.  This is quite dangerous as if no files at all have been created or deleted in the root folder (`/data/oozie-admi/`) then it's changed time will not have been updated and your `/data/oozie-admi/` folder will be deleted.

So essentially that line of script would delete that directory or any subdirectories if the directory changed date is more than 48 hours ago.

I'm not sure what the `[0]` is supposed to be doing.  From a quick search I can see it might be useful if you were using this in an ["if True" type statement](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267326/why-does-if-0-execute-the-then-statement-in-bash-script) but you have no `if` statement.  At best this appears that it would be passed as an argument to the `rm` command and so you would delete a directory named `[0]` in whatever directory the script is being run as well as your `/data/oozie-admi/` directory.

Comment: What's the `[0]` signify? Not in man/info I could find, different from `"$@"` or `'{}'` ?

Comment: @Xen2050 I've done a bit of experimenting and cannot find a reason for it.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: So it's not just me ;-)  I'll go with "Maybe part of the script the OP is using" and forget about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what You need is:

```
find /data/oozie-admi/ -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime +1 | xargs rm -rf
```

or:

```
find /data/oozie-admi/ -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime +1 -exec rm -rf +
```

Both commands should work the same (on Linux), second one a bit more realiable for big number of folders.